# How and when are QoS access classes assigned to packet transmitted over wifi?

Tags: wifi, qos

There are 4 queues in WiFi system for QoS-

1- voice 
2- video 
3- best effort
4-background

How are these access classes assigned to packet transmitted over wifi ?
Can we differentiate two voice services (say Skype and Whatsapp Video call) to provide different QoS to them (using WMM or WMM-SA) ? 
Even though wifi router would have layer 3 protocol information only, is there any way to identify packets based on application ?